# Python. Если в списке есть одинаковые числа, то не могу сортировать через min

Tags: python, сортировка, index, min

Если в списке есть одинаковые числа, то сортировка через min не работает. С max вроде все нормально работает, а с min нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, из-за чего может так происходить? может проблема в index?

- 1 Вариант

  ```
  a = [56,54,85,61,0,2,9,5,74,0]
  n = len(a) 
  for i in range(n):
      k = a.index(min(a[i:]))
      a[i],a[k] = a[k],a[i]
  print(a)
  #результат [54, 85, 61, 56, 2, 9, 5, 74, 0, 0]
  ```
- 2 Вариант

  ```
  a = [56,54,85,61,0,2,9,5,74]
  n = len(a) 

  for i in range(n):
      k = a.index(min(a[i:]))
      a[i],a[k] = a[k],a[i]
  print(a)
  #результат [0, 2, 5, 9, 54, 56, 61, 74, 85]
  ```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Да и с max не работает. В этом коде просто нет сортировки.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [56, 54, 85, 61, 0, 2, 9, 5, 74, 0]
n = len(a)
for i in range(n):
    min_val = min(a[i:])
    min_idx = a.index(min_val, i)  # Ищем индекс минимального элемента среди элементов начиная с индекса i
    a[i], a[min_idx] = a[min_idx], a[i]
print(a)
# Результат [0, 0, 2, 5, 9, 54, 56, 61, 74, 85]
```

Вместо использования функции `index()`, вы можете создать подсписок `a[i:]` и найти минимальный элемент в нем с помощью функции `min()`

Comment: Можно не вводить дополнительную переменную, а просто добавить в исходном коде параметр `i` в метод `index`. 'k = a.index(min(a[i:]), i)'

Answer (score 1):

После первого перехода циклом `for` будет все так, как вы ожидали — минимальный элемент будет в начале списка:

```
[0, 56, 54, 85, 61, 2, 9, 5, 74, 0]
```

В последующих шагах `min(a[i:])` найдет значение `0` (на последней позиции среза `a[i:]`), что хорошо, **НО**

затем вы ищете это значение (`0`) в **целом** списке `а`:

```
a.index(min(a[i:]))
```

Значит, оно будет вычисляться как `a.index(0)`, найдет `0` сразу в начале списка, и вы получите индекс **этого** ноля, **а не индекс второго ноля.**

---

*Исправление:*

Ищите индекс элемента не в целом списке, а **только с позиции `i`**, т.е. вместо

```
k = a.index(min(a[i:]))
```

примените

```
k = a.index(min(a[i:]), i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Код, который вам нужен:

```
a = [56,54,85,61,0,2,9,5,74,0]
    print(sorted(a))
```

Сортирует по возрастанию!
Намного легче и удобнее!